# How can get element generated by code in Appcelerator application

Tags: javascript, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I'm building an app with appcelerator studio.
Now I want to insert by code some element in my View.

So I'm building this code:

```
 var view1 = Ti.UI.createView({
          left : 0,
          width : "35%",
      top: "30px"
      });

    var label1 = createHeader(Titanium.Locale.getString(lang+"social_history")); 

    view1.add(label1);

    function createHeader(headerText){
        var heading = Ti.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor : "#0c7b84"
        });

        var headingText = $.UI.create("Label", {
        classes: 'headerTableLabel'
        });
        headingText.text = headerText;

        heading.add(headingText);

        return heading;
    }
....
....
```

This code works, but now I want to change throught an event a text of Label1. So I'm building this code that NOT works:

```
function set_fields(lang) {
    label1.text = Titanium.Locale.getString(lang + "social_history");
}
```

How can I get the element of the view, generated by code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding label1 to view1, label1 becomes a child of view1. To get the children of a view, simply use `view.getChildren()` (returns an array of children) or `var someChild = view.children[number_of_child_in_array]` to get a certain child.

In you case, `var theLabel = view1.children[0]` should give you label1

[Appcelerator Documentation - getChildren](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-method-getChildren)